# Interpolate z-values of vertices using the surrounding area

Tags: modeling, interpolation

I've got an .obj file with a raised street (selected in the image) and uneven terrain around it and want to flatten the street, so it kind of blends in with the surrounding area.

[image]

What's important: This must not add or remove vertices, it should only change the height of the raised ones but not touch the position (x/y) otherwise or the surrounding area at all.

What makes this more complicated is that the surrounding area isn't the same height everywhere, so I can't simply <kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> without creating ugly cuts, which I won't be able to remove just by using the "smooth" tool because it doesn't take the surrounding area into account.

I'm aware I could create a nice slope by hand in sculpting mode (very carefully to not change the surrounding vertices) but is there a way to do this automatically (after selecting the area, of course) in Blender 2.91, so I can do it semi-quickly for multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

Use *Smooth* modifier with only $z$ axis selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried smoothing with the tool on the left toolbar but that doesn't take the surrounding vertices into account. I can't use the "Smooth" modifier you suggested instead either because it can't be applied in edit mode, which means that it would smooth the whole object, not just the area I selected.

Comment: @Neph you can assign a vertex group to the area you want to affect

Comment: Does that take the surrounding area into account or does it work the same way as the regular tool?

Comment: @Neph I'm not sure what you mean... Why not just test it yourself? https://i.imgur.com/f6xHmhD.gif

Comment: The regular "smooth" tool in the toolbar only flattens the area a little bit (basically gets rid of the spikes, using s+z+0 is faster in that regard) but leaves it as a plateau. I just tested it: Create the vertex group, use s+z+0 to flatten, then move the whole area down and use the modifier in object mode. A factor of 1 (any higher quickly creates new spikes) and about 200 repetitions (100 leaves a couple of bumps) managed to make it blend in with the surrounding area. The [result](https://i.imgur.com/ANwHJTA.png). Thanks! Please also add the gif and vertex group info to the answer.